# Google Chart Toolbar: live data export from google chart toolbar

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have implemented google chart with live data coming from the server. Now I want to export that data into CSV format using google chart toolbar. But I am not sure what to pass into the dataSource URL? I tried with the live data URL but it is not working.

I am using similar code as below. URL returns JSON response.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com:8082/api/v1/eis/records",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (jsonData) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        // assumes "word" is a string and "count" is a number
        data.addColumn('string', 'word');
        data.addColumn('number', 'count');

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([jsonData[i].word, jsonData[i].count]);
        }
        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('xyz'));
        chart.draw(data);
    }
});
```

Is there any solution to use this URL in a toolbar for exporting the data?

Thanks,

Comment: see [toolbar usage](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/toolbar#usage) -- _To use a toolbar, your visualization must get its data from a URL; you cannot pass in hand-populated DataTable or DataView objects._. Instead, use static method --> `google.visualization.dataTableToCsv`. See [export csv option in google visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49306136/5090771)...

Comment: toolbar's datasource accepts google spreadsheet data like this:
var components = [
          {type: 'csv', datasource: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptHnwJEfo8tALA'}
      ];
So do we any solution to use our URL directly?

Comment: maybe I misunderstood, how are you getting _live data coming from the server_? maybe share a little code, i can unmark duplicate if needed...

Comment: I have edited the question. I want to use mentioned URL in the toolbar.

Comment: not possible, json would need to be in the format found here --> [Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)