# Export to CSV functionality in Angular Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization, angular9

I am using [angular-google-charts] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-google-charts) in an Angular 9 project. The requirement is to provide an "export to csv functionality". Below is a sample code for google chart. How will the code to provide an option to download the csv fit in here:

**app.component.html**

```
<google-chart #chart  [title]="title"  [type]="type"  [data]="data"  [columnNames]="columnNames" 
  [options]="options"  [width]="width"  [height]="height"> </google-chart>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'Population (in millions)';
type = 'ColumnChart';
data = [
  ["2012", 900],
  ["2013", 1000],
  ["2014", 1170],
  ["2015", 1250],
  ["2016", 1530]
];
columnNames = ['Year', 'Asia'];
options = {};
width = 550;
height = 400;
}
```

Comment: you need to implement the ready event, found [here](https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts#events) -- then you can use the [dataTableToCsv](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#datatabletocsv) method -- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49306136/5090771) is an example...

Comment: The helper function google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(data) seems to be specific to the google charts library, if you could help us with the solution specific to angular-google charts, it wold be a great help :)

Comment: yes, if you implement the ready event, then you can get the data table from the chart wrapper and feed it to the csv method...