# Google visualization export DataView to Excel

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization, export-to-excel

I’m seeking advice on best practice for providing the user a click button to export a `DataView` behind chart/table into Excel.

I looked into the [Toolbar](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/toolbar) functionality but found this does not work because the `DataView` is  “hand-populated“ and not a URL required by the API. (Please correct me if I’m mistaken in my understanding.)

I prefer to follow/use methods which are common in the field.

Suggestions?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_ -- check out [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx), an old method I still use is to generate an xml document from the data, using the XML Spreadsheet 2003 format, which will open in Excel by default...

Comment: *I didn't know this.* -- Thank you for the hint :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it for anyone interested.

HTML:

```
<div id="div_table"></div>
<a id="exportCSV" href="">Excel</a>
```

My table object is a `.ChartWrapper` so I can use the `.getDataTable()` method later.

```
var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    options: {allowHtml: true}
});
```

JavaScript - Google visualization event listener

```
document.getElementById("exportCSV").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var csvData = table.getDataTable(); //google visualization DataTable to download
    export_CSV("exportCSV", csvData);
});
```

Javascript - function source material https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956427/7763687

```
function export_CSV(elementID, data) {

    var csvColumns;
    var csvContent;
    var downloadLink;

    // build column headings
    csvColumns = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        csvColumns += data.getColumnLabel(i);
        if (i < data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1) {
            csvColumns += ',';
        }
    }
    csvColumns += '\n';

    // get data rows
    csvContent = csvColumns + google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(data);

    //New Download Link - works in chrome and mozilla
    downloadLink = document.getElementById(elementID);
    downloadLink.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csvContent);
    downloadLink.download = 'data.csv';
    downloadLink.target = '_blank';
}
```

This worked ok for my application.  Cheers!

Comment: I am trying to do that same thing and have tried to use your code but I must be referencing the table wrong because I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: table.getDataTable is not a function` (My DataTable handle is table) - Can you add your DataTable setup for a bit more context?

Comment: The above code works because we use a `.ChartWrapper` to build the table.  I added my table object to the answer post for clarification. You can also take a look at the method `.getDataTable()` in the Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods_2) . You can see a working example of using a  `.ChartWrapper` in the stack overflow link I referenced in the answer post.  Hope this helps.