# Google Table Chart CSV returns scientific notation instead of string

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a script which creates a csv file when "Download CSV" is clicked.

When `partId` is all numbers, is there a way to make the CSV recognize it as `'string'` (defined in `DataTable`) instead of scientific notation?

See picture csv result column B:

- row 4 partId begins with 1 -> shows as 1.23457E+12
- row 5 partId begins with 0 -> shows as 1.23457E+11 (leading zero gets dropped)

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(gChart0);

function gChart0() {
  drawChart();
}

function drawChart() {

  var result = [{
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "partId": '1234567890xxx',
    "someNumber": 0 
  }, {
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "partId": '1234567890yyy',
    "someNumber": 0 
  }, {
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "partId": '1234567890111',
    "someNumber": 0 
  }, {
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "partId": '0123456789222',
    "someNumber": 0 
  }];

  //Create DataTable
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Calendar Week');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Part Id');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Some Number');

  var dataArray = [];
  $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
    dataArray.push([
      obj.calendarWeek,
      obj.partId,
      obj.someNumber
    ]);
  });
  data.addRows(dataArray);

  //Options

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('div_dashboard'));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'StringFilter',
    containerId: 'div_categoryPicker1',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 1,
      matchType: 'any',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowNone: true
      }
    }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    options: {
      width: '100%',
      height: 'auto',
      page: 'enable',
      pageSize: '15',
      sort: 'enable',
      allowHtml: true
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(dashboard, 'ready', function() {
    document.getElementById("a_exportCSV").addEventListener("click", function() {
      var csvData = table.getDataTable();
      lib_export_CSV("a_exportCSV", csvData);
    });
  });

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker1], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);

} //END  function drawChart()

function lib_export_CSV(elementID, data) {
  //This version takes care of adding the column names
  //https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956427/7763687

  var csvColumns;
  var csvContent;
  var downloadLink;

  // build column headings
  csvColumns = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    csvColumns += data.getColumnLabel(i);
    if (i < data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1) {
      csvColumns += ',';
    }
  }
  csvColumns += '\n';

  // get data rows - .replace('#', '') because this one breaks encodeURI(csvContent) 
  csvContent = csvColumns + google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(data).replace('#', '');

  //New Download Link - works in chrome and mozilla
  downloadLink = document.getElementById(elementID);
  downloadLink.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csvContent);
  downloadLink.download = 'data.csv';
  downloadLink.target = '_blank';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="div_dashboard"></div><br />
<div id="div_categoryPicker1"></div><br />
<div id="div_table"></div><br />
<a id="a_exportCSV" href="">Download CSV</a>
```

Comment: I'm not finding a good solution. Is the only point of downloading csv is so it will open in Excel? If so, we can build a different type of download using xml...

Comment: I would be interested in seeing an xml solution.  The user community is just interested in seeing the output in Excel.  How it gets there is up to us.  I don't have any experience with XML.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a solution using CSV,
where `partId` with all numbers is shown as string.

however, if the purpose of CSV is to download the data to Excel,
we can use the XML Spreadsheet 2003 format.
(it is an old format, but still works, and we can build it with text)
even though the file extension is `.xml`, it *should* open in Excel by default.

there are some limitations, but mainly advanced features,
such as shapes, images, tables, etc.

otherwise, there are options to format workbooks and sheets just about any way you want.

following are some reference materials to help with the various options and techniques.
[XML Spreadsheet Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa140066(v=office.10))
[Introduction to SpreadsheetML](http://m8y.org/Microsoft_Office_2003_XML_Reference_Schemas/Help/html/spreadsheetml_HV01151864.htm)

see the following working snippet.
here, I use HTML templates to store the xml and build the spreadsheet.
I've only provided the minimal content to get the spreadsheet built and downloaded.
but, the `partId` column appears as desired.

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(gChart0);

function gChart0() {
  drawChart();
}

function drawChart() {

  var result = [{
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "partId": '1234567890xxx',
    "someNumber": 0
  }, {
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "partId": '1234567890yyy',
    "someNumber": 0
  }, {
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "partId": '1234567890111',
    "someNumber": 0
  }, {
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "partId": '0123456789222',
    "someNumber": 0
  }];

  //Create DataTable
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Calendar Week');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Part Id');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Some Number');

  var dataArray = [];
  $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
    dataArray.push([
      obj.calendarWeek,
      obj.partId,
      obj.someNumber
    ]);
  });
  data.addRows(dataArray);

  //Options

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('div_dashboard'));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'StringFilter',
    containerId: 'div_categoryPicker1',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 1,
      matchType: 'any',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowNone: true
      }
    }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    options: {
      width: '100%',
      height: 'auto',
      page: 'enable',
      pageSize: '15',
      sort: 'enable',
      allowHtml: true
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(dashboard, 'ready', function() {
    document.getElementById("a_exportXML").addEventListener("click", function() {
      var csvData = table.getDataTable();
      lib_export_XML("a_exportXML", csvData);
    });
  });

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker1], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);

} //END  function drawChart()

function lib_export_XML(elementID, data) {
  var blobExcelFile;
  var browserIsIE;
  var downloadLink;
  var formatDateISO;
  var xlCols;
  var xlRows;
  var xlSheet;
  var xlStyle;
  var xlType;
  var xlWb;

  // determine if current browser is IE
  browserIsIE = false || !!document.documentMode;

  // create google date formatter
  formatDateISO = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ'
  });

  // build column headings
  xlRows = '';
  xlCols = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    xlCols += renderTemplate('template-excel-cell', {
      Style: 's10',
      Type: 'String',
      Value: data.getColumnLabel(i)
    });
  }
  xlRows += renderTemplate('template-excel-row', {
    Columns: xlCols
  });

  // build rows
  for (var r = 0; r < data.getNumberOfRows(); r++) {
    xlCols = '';
    for (var c = 0; c < data.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
      // set style, type based on column type
      switch (data.getColumnType(c)) {
        case 'string':
          xlStyle = 's11';
          xlType = 'String';
          break;

        case 'number':
          xlStyle = 's12';
          xlType = 'Number';
          break;

        default:
          xlStyle = 's10';
          xlType = 'String';
      }

      // add column
      xlCols += renderTemplate('template-excel-cell', {
        Style: xlStyle,
        Type: xlType,
        Value: data.getValue(r, c)
      });
    }

    // add row
    xlRows += renderTemplate('template-excel-row', {
      Columns: xlCols
    });
  }

  xlSheet = renderTemplate('template-excel-sheet', {
    ColumnCount: data.getNumberOfColumns(),
    Name: 'Data',
    RowCount: data.getNumberOfRows() + 1,
    Rows: xlRows
  });

  xlWb = renderTemplate('template-excel-wb', {
    Author: 'WhiteHat',
    Created: formatDateISO.formatValue(new Date()),
    Company: 'Acme',
    Sheets: xlSheet
  });

  blobExcelFile = new Blob([xlWb], {type: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel'});

  if (browserIsIE) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blobExcelFile, 'data.xml');
  } else {
    downloadLink = document.getElementById(elementID);
    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blobExcelFile);
    downloadLink.download = 'data.xml';
  }
}

// render html template
function renderTemplate(templateId, templateValues) {
  var templateText;   // html string to return
  var templateValue;  // html value

  // get template html
  templateText = document.getElementById(templateId).innerHTML;

  // replace place holders with values
  if (templateValues) {
    for (var propHandle in templateValues) {
      if (templateValues.hasOwnProperty(propHandle)) {
        templateValue = '';
        if (templateValues[propHandle] !== null) {
          templateValue = templateValues[propHandle].toString();
        }
        if (templateValue.indexOf('$') > -1) {
          templateValue = templateValue.replace(new RegExp('\\$', 'g'), '$$$');
        }
        if (templateText.indexOf('{{' + propHandle + '}}') > -1) {
          templateText = templateText.replace(new RegExp('{{' + propHandle + '}}', 'g'), templateValue);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return templateText.trim();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="div_dashboard">
  <div id="div_categoryPicker1"></div>
  <div id="div_table"></div>
</div>
<a id="a_exportXML" href="#">Download XML</a>

<!-- template: excel template - workbook -->
<script id="template-excel-wb" type="text/html">
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
  <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
      <Author>{{Author}}</Author>
      <LastAuthor>{{Author}}</LastAuthor>
      <Created>{{Created}}</Created>
      <Company>{{Company}}</Company>
      <Version>14.00</Version>
    </DocumentProperties>
    <x:ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
      <x:ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
      <x:ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
    </x:ExcelWorkbook>
    <Styles>
      <!-- Default style -->
      <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
        <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Center" />
        <Borders/>
        <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000" />
        <Interior/>
        <NumberFormat/>
        <Protection/>
      </Style>

      <!-- General format -->
      <Style ss:ID="s10">
      </Style>

      <!-- Text format -->
      <Style ss:ID="s11">
        <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
      </Style>

      <!-- Accounting format -->
      <Style ss:ID="s12">
        <NumberFormat ss:Format="_(* #,##0.0_);_(* \(#,##0.0\);_(* &quot;-&quot;??_);_(@_)"/>
      </Style>
    </Styles>
    {{Sheets}}
  </Workbook>
</script>

<!-- template: excel template - worksheet -->
<script id="template-excel-sheet" type="text/html">
  <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="{{SheetName}}">
    <ss:Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="{{ColumnCount}}" ss:ExpandedRowCount="{{RowCount}}" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
      {{Rows}}
    </ss:Table>
    <x:WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
      <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>
      <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>
    </x:WorksheetOptions>
  </ss:Worksheet>
</script>

<!-- template: excel template - row -->
<script id="template-excel-row" type="text/html">
  <ss:Row ss:AutoFitHeight="1">{{Columns}}</ss:Row>
</script>

<!-- template: excel template - cell value -->
<script id="template-excel-cell" type="text/html">
  <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="{{Style}}"><ss:Data ss:Type="{{Type}}">{{Value}}</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
</script>
```

Comment: note: another trick is to find various formatting options is to save an existing workbook as XML Spreadsheet 2003, then open the XML file in notepad, or other text editor, to see what Excel generated...